# Is there a way to get stricted date parsing than setting leniency to false?

Tags: java, parsing, date, datetime

I'm kind of new to Java programming and I need to parse a date I get as a string. The format has to be `dd-MM-yyyy` but it's irrelevant for the answer I think.

To parse that string into a `Calendar` object I'm using `SimpleDateFormat` in the following way:

```
String example = "16-09-2013";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
formato.setLenient(false);
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(format.parse(date));
```

And the result is the one to be expected.

The problem is that it would also parse correctly something like `"16-9-2013"` (note the absence of leading 0 in the month) and when that happens I'd prefer to throw the exception and catch it to notify appropriately.

I'm restricted to use Java SE without any additions (which takes out Joda Time and the like), so I wonder, is there a way to parse a date string so that it only succeeds if it strictly complies with the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to check that the string matches the expected format, regex is built into Java SE http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Then you can use the code you have above to check that it is in fact a valid date, and not some invalid date such as feb 31 which the regex would not catch.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I completely forgot about regular expressions; that way I'd enforce formatting while still retaining sanity checks on the date.